# drawing latex table multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicolumn

Hi can someone please help me to draw this table in latex

[image]

i had used this code by i couldn't found how to add a multicolumn in Kpss test column

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering 
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}

  \hline

 \textbf{Sector}& \textbf{t-Statistic}& \textbf{Probability}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{KPSS Test}}\\

 \hline

  \textbf{AGRICULTURE}& 0.31028&    0.0326 \\
  \hline

  \textbf{CONSTRUCTION}&-1.3716&    0.1562& \\
    \hline


  \textbf{ENERGY}&  -2.0059&    0.0438 \\
  \hline

    \textbf{HOUSEHOLD}& -1.99411&   0.0450 \\
      \hline

     \textbf{MANUFACTURE}&  -1.7018&    0.0178\\
      \hline

    \textbf{MINING}&    -2.3856&    0.0176\\
      \hline

    \textbf{TOURISM}&   -2.3251&    0.0206\\
        \hline

\end{tabular}
    \caption{Augmented DickeyFuller and KPSS Test Statistics for Transformed Indices}
    \label{tab:Augmented DickeyFuller and KPSS Test Statistics for Transfor med Indices}
\end{table}
```

Comment: `\multicolumn{4}{c}{KPSS Test}` at the right point?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is incomplete. Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left = 2.5cm, right = 2.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
    \centering 
    \begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|r|r|r|r|}

        \hline
        &&&\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{KPSS Test}}\\ \cline{4-7}

        \textbf{Sector}& \textbf{t-Statistic}& \textbf{Probability}& LM Stat& \% 1 Level&\% 5 Level&\% 10 Level \\

        \hline

        \textbf{AGRICULTURE}& 0.31028&    0.0326&&&& \\
        \hline

        \textbf{CONSTRUCTION}&-1.3716&    0.1562&&&& \\
        \hline


        \textbf{ENERGY}&  -2.0059&    0.0438&&&& \\
        \hline

        \textbf{HOUSEHOLD}& -1.99411&   0.0450&&&& \\
        \hline

        \textbf{MANUFACTURE}&  -1.7018&    0.0178&&&&\\
        \hline

        \textbf{MINING}&    -2.3856&    0.0176&&&&\\
        \hline

        \textbf{TOURISM}&   -2.3251&    0.0206&&&&\\
        \hline

    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Augmented DickeyFuller and KPSS Test Statistics for Transformed Indices}
    \label{tab:Augmented DickeyFuller and KPSS Test Statistics for Transfor med Indices}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @haithem then please accept Carlos's answer by clicking the green check mark so the question is closed.